# Server Side Includes for HTML

Tags: html, iis, iis-8, server-side-includes

How do I enable Server Side Includes for html file hosted on IIS 8.5? Like:

```
<!--#include virtual="filename.htm"-->
```

Currently, I don't see include file (html) content when I open page in browser.

Edit: I manually added module mapping of ServerSideIncludeModule for website & still doesn't work.

Comment: Is this a .shtml file?

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct module mapping handler.

When you add the module mapping under *Handler Mapping* in IIS 8.5 double check that you specify *.html as the file type; don't forget the asterisk (the *).  I had added it only as .html, and that won't work.

Also, when you add the module mapping, make sure you click on the "Request Restrictions..." button; on the Mapping tab for restrictions, the checkbox for "Invoke handler only if request is mapped to:" should be checked, and the selection should be set to File.  More importantly, on the Verbs tab for the restriction, make sure that the lower dot is selected for "One of the following verbs:" and in the field below you should have "GET, HEAD, POST".  Lastly, on the Access tab you should have "Script" selected.

Lastly, if you haven't done the appcmd.exe to set ssiDisable to false, you'll need to run this at at command prompt (run the command prompt as Admin).

```html
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv

appcmd.exe set config "Name_of_website_as_it_appears_in_IIS_Manager" -section:system.webServer/serverSideInclude /ssiExecDisable:"False" /commit:apphost
```